# Entity Framework Inserting Object Twice

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm having trouble with Entity Framework 6. It appears that EF is trying to insert the same object twice. I have reviewed lots of posts about this and tried to format my solution to accompany many suggestions from these posts. At this point my service is creating a new attribute and assigning the foreign key for its related attribute definition. The service is then calling a repository method which creates a new context, adds the newly created attribute to the context and attempts to save which fails for index violation (if the index is removed EF will insert two identical attribute records).

I've also tried creating a separate repository method to return the corresponding Attribute Definition object under a new context, attaching the returned Attribute Definition Object to the Attribute w/foreign key assigned. This results in EF creating new Attribute Definition for each Attribute (even though they already exist in the database) and inserting the new Attributes related to the new Attribute Definitions.

**this issue is only occurring when attempting to insert multiple Attributes. If I run the service by passing a single Attribute it processes correctly on all codes paths.**

Another note, the following test method runs correctly, but then the same code is copied into the service it fails for index violation as above:

**Test Method**

```
[TestMethod]
public void Attribute()
{
    try
    {
        using (context)
        {
            List<Domain.Attribute> attributeList = new List<Domain.Attribute>();

            AttributeDefinition attributeDefinitionOne = context.AttributeDefinition.FirstOrDefault(m => m.AttributeDefinitionId == 1);

            Domain.Attribute attributeOne = new Domain.Attribute
            {
                AttributeDefinitionId = 1,
                ObjectId = 10074,
                ObjectType = "CD",
                AttributeValue = "Test Business Definition",
                CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                CreateUser = Environment.UserName,
                LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,
                LastModifiedUser = Environment.UserName,
            };

            attributeList.Add(attributeOne);

            AttributeDefinition attributeDefintionTwo = context.AttributeDefinition.FirstOrDefault(m => m.AttributeDefinitionId == 2);

            Domain.Attribute attributeTwo = new Domain.Attribute
            {
                AttributeDefinitionId = 2,
                ObjectId = 10074,
                ObjectType = "CD",
                AttributeValue = "Test Stakeholder Definition",
                CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                CreateUser = Environment.UserName,
                LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,
                LastModifiedUser = Environment.UserName
            };

            attributeList.Add(attributeTwo);

            foreach (Domain.Attribute attribute in attributeList)
            {
                //context.AttributeDefinition.Attach(attribute.AttributeDefinition);
                context.Attribute.Add(attribute);
                context.SaveChanges();

            }


            Domain.Attribute businessAttribute = context.Attribute.FirstOrDefault(m => m.AttributeDefinitionId == 1 && m.ObjectId == 10074 && m.ObjectType == "CD");
            Domain.Attribute stakeAttribute = context.Attribute.FirstOrDefault(m => m.AttributeDefinitionId == 2 && m.ObjectId == 10074 && m.ObjectType == "CD");

            Assert.IsNotNull(businessAttribute);
            Assert.IsNotNull(stakeAttribute);


        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }

}
```

**Attribute Object**

```
public class Attribute
{
    public int AttributeId { get; set; }
    public int AttributeDefinitionId { get; set; }
    public int ObjectId { get; set; }
    public string ObjectType { get; set; }
    public string AttributeValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string CreateUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedUser { get; set; }

    public virtual AttributeDefinition AttributeDefinition { get; set; }

}
```

**Attribute Definition Object**

```
public class AttributeDefinition
{
    public AttributeDefinition()
    {
        Attributes = new List<Domain.Attribute>();
    }
    public int AttributeDefinitionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string CreateUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedUser { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

**Attribute EF Mapping**

```
public AttributeMap() {
    ToTable("Attribute");
    HasKey(a => a.AttributeId);

    Property(a => a.AttributeId)
        .HasColumnName("AttributeId")
        .HasColumnType("INT");

    Property(a => a.AttributeDefinitionId)
        .HasColumnName("AttributeDefinitionId")
        .HasColumnType("INT");

    Property(a => a.ObjectId)
        .HasColumnName("ObjectId")
        .HasColumnType("INT");

    Property(a => a.ObjectType)
        .HasColumnName("ObjectType")
        .HasColumnType("VARCHAR")
        .HasMaxLength(2);

    Property(a => a.AttributeValue)
        .HasColumnName("AttributeValue")
        .HasColumnType("VARCHAR");

    Property(a => a.CreateDate)
        .HasColumnName("CreateDate")
        .HasColumnType("DATETIME");

    Property(a => a.CreateUser)
        .HasColumnName("CreateUser")
        .HasColumnType("VARCHAR");

    Property(a => a.LastModifiedDate)
        .HasColumnName("LastModifiedDate")
        .HasColumnType("DATETIME");

    Property(a => a.LastModifiedUser)
        .HasColumnName("LastModifiedUser")
        .HasColumnType("VARCHAR");

    HasRequired(attribute => attribute.AttributeDefinition)
        .WithMany(attributeDefinition => attributeDefinition.Attributes)
        .HasForeignKey(attribute => attribute.AttributeDefinitionId);
```

**Attribute Definition EF Mapping**

```
ToTable("AttributeDefinition");
HasKey(a => a.AttributeDefinitionId);

Property(a => a.AttributeDefinitionId)
    .HasColumnName("AttributeDefinitionId")
    .HasColumnType("INT");

Property(a => a.Name)
    .HasColumnName("Name")
    .HasColumnType("VARCHAR");

Property(a => a.Description)
    .HasColumnName("Description")
    .HasColumnType("VARCHAR");

Property(a => a.CreateDate)
    .HasColumnName("CreateDate")
    .HasColumnType("DATETIME");

Property(a => a.CreateUser)
    .HasColumnName("CreateUser")
    .HasColumnType("VARCHAR");

Property(a => a.LastModifiedDate)
    .HasColumnName("LastModifiedDate")
    .HasColumnType("DATETIME");

Property(a => a.LastModifiedUser)
    .HasColumnName("LastModifiedUser")
    .HasColumnType("VARCHAR");

HasMany(attributeDefintion => attributeDefintion.Attributes)
    .WithRequired(attribute => attribute.AttributeDefinition)
    .HasForeignKey(attribute => attribute.AttributeDefinitionId);
```

**Service Method:**

```
public void SaveAttribute(string objectId, string objectType, IEnumerable<AttributeContract> attributes)
{

    //List of attribute definition Id
    List<int> attributeDefinitionIdList = new List<int>();
    //List<Domain.Attribute> attributeList = new List<Domain.Attribute>();

    foreach (AttributeContract attributeContract in attributes)
    {
        int iAttributeDefinitionId = Convert.ToInt32(attributeContract.AttributeDefinitionId);
        attributeDefinitionIdList.Add(iAttributeDefinitionId);

        int iObjectId = Convert.ToInt32(attributeContract.ObjectId);
        DateTime dCreateDate = Convert.ToDateTime(attributeContract.CreateDate);
        DateTime dLastModifiedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(attributeContract.LastModifiedDate);

        Domain.Attribute currentAttibute = new Domain.Attribute
        {
            AttributeDefinitionId = iAttributeDefinitionId,
            ObjectId = iObjectId,
            ObjectType = attributeContract.ObjectType,
            AttributeValue = attributeContract.AttributeValue,
            CreateDate = dCreateDate,
            CreateUser = attributeContract.CreateUser,
            LastModifiedDate = dLastModifiedDate,
            LastModifiedUser = attributeContract.LastModifiedUser
        };

        _repo.SaveAttribute(currentAttibute);

        //attributeList.Add(currentAttibute);
    }

    //IEnumerable<AttributeDefinition> currentAttributeDefintiionList = _repo.GetAttributeDefinition(attributeDefinitionIdList);

    //foreach (AttributeDefinition attributeDefinition in currentAttributeDefintiionList)
    //{
    //    //Assign the attribute definition to the attribute
    //    var attribute = attributeList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AttributeDefinitionId == attributeDefinition.AttributeDefinitionId);
    //    attribute.AttributeDefinition = attributeDefinition;
    //}

    //_repo.SaveAttribute(attributeList);

}
```

**Attribute Repository**

```
public void SaveAttribute(Domain.Attribute attribute)
{
    using (var context = new ShpoDataDictionaryContext(new ContextConfiguration()))
    {
        context.Attribute.Add(attribute);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in the service and not in your code calling the service.  If the code only tries to insert the object twice when you put it in the service, I'd check the code that is making that service call.

Comment: When I run the debugger, the error occurs without leaving the service. So I don't believe the error is in the calling code. I've also checked the objects that are coming to and from the service/repository and the IEnumerables all appear to only ever contain the number of objects expected. So, for example, we're not passing in two of the same attribute.

Comment: You don't want to call repo.SaveAttribute in a for each loop like that, you are breaking the unit of work because you call SaveChanges() multiple times. Most of the time you will only ever want to call SaveChanges() once per request. You're commented code had the right idea, you should do something like `_repo.SaveAttributes(attributes);` .... `context.Attribute.AddRange(attributes);`. You should get out of the habit of naming things like attributeList, instead name it attributes. It's a form of hungarian notation which we have moved away from as a community.

Comment: Awesome - thank you for the pointer :-), I knew that calling the _repo.SaveChange inside that foreach wasn't the best approach. However, I'm fairly desperate at this point. If I revert back to taking IEnumberable and using the EF AddRange(), any thoughts as to why EF is creating new Attribute Definitions despite me providing the proper objects/foreign keys for the related Attribute Definition in the new Attribute declaration?